# How to use autocomplete for HTML inside react in WebStorm IDE?

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

Since we need to write a lot of HTML inside js scripts, I want to have `Emmet` autocomplete inside JavaScript for HTML tags: if I enter `a` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key it should insert default link string.

Comment: Accordingly to WebStorm docs it should be working there. Can you please provide some basic sample project (and specify a file/place) where it does not work?

Comment: Sorry, it seems You are right, we can mark it's as right answer if you create. It seems i had some problems in nearest code and that's why it didn't work. But i saw no warnings. Now i can use this.

Comment: Considering the issue -- either answer with your explanation ("there was error in my code ...") or (possibly better -- at least I would) consider deleting this question.